# Pymodbus Asynchronous Server with RTU framer not working

Tags: modbus, pymodbus

I'm trying to implement a modbus asynchronous serial server with the library Pymodbus. I'm using a ModbusRtuFramer as a frame template. Unfortunately, when I send a command, it looks like the bytes are splitted and the frame is not recognized. I post both the code and the log.

```
        StartSerialServer(context, identity=identity,
                framer=ModbusRtuFramer,
                port='/dev/ttyS2',
                timeout=0.1,
                baudrate=9600,
                bytesize=8,
                parity='N',
                stopbits=1)
```

I send the command 03102c0002 (read 2 holding registers starting from address 102c. The log says:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [b'\x01'] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x0 0x2 0x1 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x0 0x2 0x1 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [b'\x01'] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x0 0x2 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x0 0x2 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [b'\x02'] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x2 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x3 0x10 0x2c 0x0
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x3 0x10 0x2c 0x0
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x2 0x1 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x2 0x1 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [b'\x01'] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x3 0x10 0x2c
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.asynchronous:Data Received: 0x0 0x2 0x1 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x0 0x2 0x1 0x2
```

Comment: what version of pymodbus are you using?